# cellForRowAtIndexPath not called for all sections

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a UITableView that has five sections. Just as the title describes cellForRowAtIndexPath is only being called for the first four.  All connections have been made concerning the datasource and delegate.  Also, my numberOfSectionsInTableView clearly returns 5.  Printing out the number of sections from within cellForRowAtIndexPath shows the correct number, thus confirming that cellForRowAtIndexPath is simply not being called for all sections.  What on earth is going on?  I looked pretty hard for an answer to this question but could't find one.  If this has already been answered please forgive me and point me in the correct direction.

My cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)theTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [theTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    switch (indexPath.section) {
        case 0:
            cell.textLabel.text = ticket.description;
            break;
        case 1:
            cell.textLabel.text = ticket.ticketStatus;
            break;
        case 2:
            cell.textLabel.text = ticket.priority;
            break;
        case 3:
            cell.textLabel.text = ticket.customerOfficePhone;
            break;
        case 4: {
            //This never ever gets executed
            Comment *comment = [ticket.comments objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            cell.textLabel.text = comment.commentContent;
            break;
        }
    }

    return cell;
}
```

My numberOfSectionsInTableView:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 5;
}
```

My numberOfRowsInSection:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    NSInteger numberOfRows;

    if (section == 4) {
        numberOfRows = [ticket.comments count];
    }
    else {
        numberOfRows = 1;
    }

    return numberOfRows;
}
```

Any suggestions are appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does your table view continue to display everything except the last section when you scroll the table view? What does your `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` look like?

Comment: what about numberOfRows? what number it returns?

Comment: My table view displays all sections (except the one in question) including their section titles.  Oddly enough the section title for the fifth section is being displayed but there are simply no cells for the section.  As for numberOfRows, for that particular section it returns the number of items in an array.  Printing out the count of that array shows that it is filled with 2 items.

Comment: Looks like `[ticket.comments count]` is 0.

Comment: does your tableview show no cells at section 4? or shows empty cells?

Comment: It shows absolutely nothing.  Its simply the section header followed by a space where there should be a table cell.  Also, yuji, I've checked to make sure [ticket.comments count] was not zero.

Comment: @Wynn Really? Try putting an `NSLog` in your `numberOfRowsInSection:` so that it logs the section and the number of rows.

Comment: I'd try putting NSLog(@"%@", cell.textLabel.text) within your case 4: of tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: to see if it actually prints anything. Also, if you used IB I would double check the width, height if the UITable you're using, and if you have any additional code that accesses the UIScrollView of the UITable in question.

Comment: try changing the line: `[ticket.comments count];` for some number like 1,2... if you see empty cells the error is probably the `ticket.comments` array.

Comment: try putting an nslog in case 4 to check if that case is executed.if it is executing try to alloc and init the comment object before passing value to it. debug the code line by line

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ah-ha!  I figured it out.  I had forgotten that I had hard coded the frame for my table view and added it as a subview with the scroll disabled to a scroll view.  Unfortunately both the scroll view and the tableview were too small in terms of height to hold the fifth section which i suppose was the reason cellForRowAtIndexPath was being called for all sections except the fifth one.  Readjusting the height of my table view and scroll view to be a little bigger has solved my problem.

Comment: Just had the same problem, this might not be that unusual. Apple makes it really difficult to debug when ignoring rendering cells below the tableHeight. Maybe a warning should be thrown on debug mode. Thanks for pointing me to the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

**Consider this as a comment. Actually I can't do all this in the comment.**

**EDIT:**

For 
`[ticket.comments count];`  is not Zero means then what is the count?.
 Check an if condition in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method to print `ticket.comments` array only `if section == 4` like this.

```
if(indexPath.section == 4){

NSLog(@"Ticket Array:%@",ticket.comments);

}
```

And Another Question:

What is `ticket.comments` actually? If that is an array, then is that having "`Comment`" object or anything else? If it's having `comment object` then try this in **case 4**.

```
case 4:
         {
            Comment *comment = (Comment *)[ticket.comments objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            cell.textLabel.text = comment.commentContent;
            break;
         }
```

I hope this comment will help you.

Comment: The braces are because you can't declare a variable on the first line after a `case`. It's a "language feature"

Comment: @jrturton Thanks for your nice information. Actually i dont know that before. i m gonna edit my code then.